# Easiest way to password protect entire YII site?

Tags: php, authentication, yii

I want to set a password for my entire YII site so I can demo it to only certain people. How do I do that?

Comment: For Apache, .htaccess & .htpasswd should do the job.

Comment: Dont want to do that because password protect in htaccess affects local repo copy.

Comment: you can choose not to add the htaccess files to your repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Yii access control filter system and the basic UserIdentity file setup they have in their blog demo. Then, instead of allowing any guest users to see pages, just require a logged in user

Answer (score 0):

Using Yii access control - not best solution for this case, it may break your app logic.

It is also possible to use HTTP authentication for this case.
On VPS - using Apache and paswd.
Most simple way - with pure PHP http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php